How do I fetch all PHAssets that contain an edit (filter on hasAdjustment)?
I am trying to retrieve all PHAssets from the Photos Library that have been edited. PHAsset contains the "hasAdjustments" boolean variable but I cannot use that in an NSPredicate to filter for edited photos.
What is the proper mechanism to filter out non-edited photos?
Here is the code I have written that crashes:
let formatString = "mediaType = %d && hasAdjustments == YES"
               
let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
            
allPhotosOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: formatString, PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)

allPhotosOptions.includeAssetSourceTypes = [.typeUserLibrary, .typeiTunesSynced, .typeCloudShared]

return PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)


I got it to work by using the following logic:
let editedPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                editedPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
                
let format = "(adjustmentFormatIdentifier == %@)"
                
editedPhotosOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: format, bundleID)
                
editedPhotosOptions.includeAssetSourceTypes = [.typeUserLibrary, .typeiTunesSynced, .typeCloudShared]
                
let editedAssetsFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: editedPhotosOptions)
                

